i'm currently facing a pb with Hover in a chessGame
first i created the over effect and get sure it works but when i added Input.getmousebutton it interfers with the hover and it's not showing up anymore previusly wherever i move my mouse on the board the square i hover changes its color but now it's not
    RaycastHit info;
    Ray ray = currentCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out info, 150, LayerMask.GetMask("Square","Hover","Highlight")))
    {
        //Get the indexes of the Square you hit
        Vector2Int hitPosition = LookUpSquareIndex(info.transform.gameObject);

        // From not hovering to hovering
        if (currentHover == -Vector2Int.one)
        {
            currentHover = hitPosition;
            Squares[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
        }

        // From hovering one square to hovering another square
        if (currentHover != hitPosition)
        {
            Squares[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = containsValidMove(ref availableMoves, currentHover) ? LayerMask.NameToLayer("Highlight") : LayerMask.NameToLayer("Square");
            currentHover = hitPosition;
            Squares[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
        }
        //pressing the mouse button
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y] != null)
            {

                //Is it Our Turn
                if ((chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].team==0 && isWhiteTurn) || (chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].team == 1 && !isWhiteTurn))
                {

                    currentlyDragging = chessPieces[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y];
                    //getting a list of available Moves , heighlight the available moves
                    availableMoves = currentlyDragging.GetAvailableMoves(ref chessPieces, SQUARE_COUNT_X, SQUARE_COUNT_Y);
                    //Getting a Special Moves List 
                    specialMove = currentlyDragging.GetSpecialMoves(ref chessPieces, ref moveList, ref availableMoves);
                    highlightSquares();
                }
            }

        }
        // Releasing the mouse Button
        if (currentlyDragging != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            Vector2Int previousPosition = new Vector2Int(currentlyDragging.currentX, currentlyDragging.currentY);

            bool validMove = MoveTo(currentlyDragging, hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y);
            if (!validMove)
                currentlyDragging.setPosition(GetSquaresCenter(previousPosition.x, previousPosition.y));

            currentlyDragging = null;
            removehighlightSquares();

        }

        else
        { 
            if (currentHover != -Vector2Int.one)
            {
                Squares[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = (containsValidMove(ref availableMoves, currentHover)) ? LayerMask.NameToLayer("Highlight") : LayerMask.NameToLayer("Square");
                currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;

                if (currentlyDragging && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
                {
                    currentlyDragging.setPosition(GetSquaresCenter(currentlyDragging.currentX, currentlyDragging.currentY));
                    currentlyDragging = null;
                    removehighlightSquares(); 
                }
            }
        }

        // while dragging a piece
        if (currentlyDragging)
        {
            Plane horizontalePlane = new Plane(Vector3.up , Vector3.up*Yoffset/1000);
            float distance = 0.0f;
            if(horizontalePlane.Raycast(ray, out distance))
                currentlyDragging.setPosition(ray.GetPoint(distance)+Vector3.up*dragOffset);
        }

    }

i tried to add multiple functions such us handleHoerEffect and HandleMouseButtonUp and Down

I think the issue might be with the else here.
    // Releasing the mouse Button
    if (currentlyDragging != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
    {
        //your code
    }
    else
    { 
        if (currentHover != -Vector2Int.one)
        {
            Squares[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = (containsValidMove(ref availableMoves, currentHover)) ? LayerMask.NameToLayer("Highlight") : LayerMask.NameToLayer("Square");
            currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;

            //your code
        }
    }

I am guessing this code is running inside the Update() loop or something similar. Frame 1 the below condition will be true and currentHover will be assined a value:
    if (currentHover == -Vector2Int.one)
    {
        currentHover = hitPosition;
        Squares[hitPosition.x, hitPosition.y].layer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Hover");
    }

Next frame if you haven't released the mouse button this condition will be false: (currentlyDragging != null && Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)) which will route the code in to the else statement mentioned above and if (currentHover != -Vector2Int.one) will be true as it was assigned a value in the previous frame
which will eventually lead to the layer being assigned to LayerMask.NameToLayer("Square") and the current hover being set to a default value and if my above assumptions are correct, this cycle will continue
                Squares[currentHover.x, currentHover.y].layer = (containsValidMove(ref availableMoves, currentHover)) ? LayerMask.NameToLayer("Highlight") : LayerMask.NameToLayer("Square");
            currentHover = -Vector2Int.one;

I couldn't test this fully locally as the code snipped provided only shows a small bit of context so my original assumptions could be totally false, but I hope this helps somehow regardless
